# How does liquibase handle execution from multiple users?

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

We have a PostgreSQL database that has consistently been updated using liquibase by a single user (a DB owner role). We recently ran an update command as another user (a system owner) and it registered as if it was a new DB/schema, meaning that liquibase tried to execute all changesets since the beginning, not just those that we expected to be the last few that were not in the databasechangelog table. Obviously this failed since those changesets had already been applied as the other user. However, it raised the question of how to handle this. Do you know why it's doing this? Is this a DB-specific issue or is this an issue at the liquibase level? Or is this an issue at all and we should accept as part of our business processes that all updates to a particular DB need to be executed by the same user?

Comment: Mabye the other user ran liquibase while using a copy of the changeset files so that the path was different? The whole path is part of the id!

Answer (score 0):

Liquibase determines which changeSets have ran by selecting from the DATABASECHANGELOG table. What I would guess is happening is that the new user has a different default schema and so is looking in a different place for that table.

Depending on how you run Liquibase, there is a changelogSchemaName or similar attribute to control where Liquibase looks for the table.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Liquibase does is user-agnostic and that information is not recorded nor needed in the DATABASECHANGELOG.